# Использование переменной из 1 скрипта в другом Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть следующий скрипт и я хотел бы использовать переменную temp в другом скрипте. Не могли бы вы подробно рассказать - как? Пробовал разными нагугленными способами, но никак не могу дойти.

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
        public void StartGame()
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
        public static void InputX(string X)
        {
            float temp = float.Parse(X);   
        }
        public static void InputY(int N)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем скрипте `temp` - это локальная переменная метода `InputX`, она существует только пока выполняется метод. Для того, чтобы переменная была доступна извне, объявите её в классе:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
        public float temp;

        public void StartGame()
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
        public static void InputX(string X)
        {
            temp = float.Parse(X);   
        }
}
```

Обратите внимание на модификатор `public`, он отвечает за [уровень доступности](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) переменной.

Далее. В Unity объект `MonoBehaviour` (т.е. игровой скрипт) существует в рантайме, если он находится на игровом объекте, который в свою очередь присутствует на активной сцене. Существует практика размещать на сценах скриптхолдеры - пустые игровые объекты, на которые вешаются нужные "общие" скрипты. Если вы создадите подобный объект, и разместите на нём скрипт `NewBehaviourScript`, обратиться к переменной можно будет примерно так:

```
GameObject.Find("ScriptHolder").GetComponent(typeof(NewBehaviourScript)).temp;
```

Вы так же можете объявить переменную-ссылку на экземпляр скрипта для удобства:

```
NewBehaviourScript beh = GameObject.Find("ScriptHolder").GetComponent(typeof(NewBehaviourScript));

float f = beh.temp * 42;
DoSomething(beh.temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если другой скрипт (пусть он называется `OtherBehaviourScript`), который будет использовать значение переменной, прикреплен к существующему в данный момент GameObject, то можно получить доступ к нему с помощью метода `FindObjectOfType` и передать переменную в какой-нибудь его публичный метод (пусть будет `SomeMethod(float)`):

```
// NewBehaviourScript.cs
FindObjectOfType<OtherBehaviourScript>().SomeMethod(temp);
```

В `OtherBehaviourScript.cs` тогда должен быть метод:

```
public void SomeMethod(float value){
   // использование значения переменной
}
```

Есть и другие способы, но применение зависит от конкретной задачи. Если расскажете подробнее про задачу, то могу подсказать, что лучше использовать.

Comment: Задача считать из поля ввода первой сцены значение X и подставить его в transform.Translate, примененный к объекту на другой сцене, как переменную (в моем случае скорость).

Comment: Объект на другой сцене должен мгновенно менять скорость исходя из введённого значения?

Answer (score 0):

1. Сначала делаем переменную `temp` доступной извне через `public` как
   сказал `eastwing`. Для этого добавляем ее в переменные вашего
   скрипта.
2. Самый простой способ получить к ней доступ в нужном вам скрипте где
   вы планируете использовать `NewBehaviourScript` объявить переменную `public`
   с типом `NewBehaviourScript`и затем в редакторе вы можете назначить
   ссылку на требуемый    объект ручками. Теперь чтобы использовать
   переменную достаточно получить ее значение по ссылке на объект
   `NewBehaviourScript`.
3. Если ссылка не может быть настроена вручную, то вы можете
   воспользоваться методами [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) для получения такой ссылки
   если оба скрипта у вас находятся на одном объекте, или искать скрипт
   через [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html), либо, что еще муторнее через поиск объекта по
   [Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html), а затем уже получать в нем компонент. Но учтите что все `Find` работают не очень быстро, и вызывать их в `Update` крайне не рекомендуется.

@RedScreed углядел что этот скрипт у вас живет в нескольких сценах, правильно понял? Попробуйте [здесь](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=26853) посмотреть, предложено несколько вариантов, вы как раз для себя выберете подходящий). Вполне можно и static переменной воспользоваться)

Comment: Зачем выполнять Find в Update. если можно получить ссылку на экземпляр компонента в Start?

Comment: Начинающие иногда так делают) Я такого поиска вообще бы в коде избегал. Лучше и надежнее делать прямые ссылки в классах и настраивать их ручками). В таком случае если кто-то удалит объект в вашей сцене вы увидите в редакторе что ссылка битая. С поиском все это обнаружится только в момент запуска..

Comment: @KingPeas проблема настройки "ручками", что сцен может быть много, и некоторые объекты переносятся между сценами. Поэтому такое действие тоже не самый лучший вариант ибо как поставить ссылку ручками если объекта на сцене изначально нет, а как раз-таки, генерится в рантайме ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - так для этого и написан пункт 3, где указаны уже предложенные способы поиска нужного скрипта, но почему то забыт самый  простой через GetComponent не указан, хотя он наиболее используемый на практике. Все зависит от степени "удаленности" исходного скрипта, были предложены самые сложные общие варианты, хотя на практике задача как правило гораздо проще и не требуют поисков объекта по имени или тэгу.